# Using SRTM data, how to get the coordinates of the peaks visible from a location?

Tags: coordinates, elevation, srtm, viewshed

Using SRTM data and a coordinate-altitude database of the peaks, I want to get the coordinates of the visible peaks from my location. I want to make an application similar to [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/peaks/id332170121?mt=8).

How is this possible?

I have to calculate the viewshed offline, because up in the mountains there is no internet connection. The view shed analysis could be done only with ArcGIS software or there is another API too? The application will be developed for IOS.

Comment: Such an analysis is called viewshed analysis

Comment: What GIS Software do you have available?

Comment: I have to calculate the viewshed offline, because up in the mountains there is no internet connection. The view shed analysis could be done only with ArcGIS software or there is another API too? The application will be developed for IOS.

Answer (score 4):

The "Marmota" project at FBK, Trento, Italy, is offering the functionality you seem to aim for: http://tev.fbk.eu/marmota/ There are a series of publications available on that site.

Furthermore, see the related question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24402/visual-impact-assessment-in-qgis-or-grass).