# Performing viewshed analysis with ArcGIS Desktop Standard License?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst, viewshed

Is there a way to perform a Viewshed Analysis with the Standard license of ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop?

If not, what is the difference (if any) between:

Viewshed with (Spatial Analyst)-
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Viewshed/009z000000v3000000/

and

Viewshed with (3D Analyst)-
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000033000000

Comment: If you are willing to use some other software, take a look into this question [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24402/visual-impact-assessment-in-qgis-or-grass/24405#24405](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24402/visual-impact-assessment-in-qgis-or-grass/24405#24405)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the licensing information, they probably share the same algorithms
Licensing Information

ArcGIS for Desktop Basic: Requires 3D Analyst or Spatial Analyst

ArcGIS for Desktop Standard: Requires 3D Analyst or Spatial Analyst

ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced: Requires 3D Analyst or Spatial Analyst

And it can't be done without one of those two extensions in ArcGIS

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between Viewshed-3D and Viewshed-Spatial in terms of functionality.

As per page 7 of the functionality matrix here:
http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf
You can add extensions to ArcGIS Server Standard. You'd have to add one of those extensions to do Viewshed.

---

My answer above was for Server in terms of licensing. Refer to Dan's answer for Desktop. My point on the same functionality is valid for both Desktop and Server

Comment: The nice thing about having viewshed available in both extensions is that you only need to buy just one of the two extensions to do viewshed. The best one to get depends on the types of other analyses you wish to do.