# Programmatically performing viewshed on points from a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, viewshed

I want to perform a viewshed analysis on multiple points in a shapefile. I'm working with a solution as seen in this post by Jakob

[Viewshed / Line of Sight analysis- as a batch process?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74813/viewshed-line-of-sight-analysis-as-a-batch-process?rq=1)

I modified his code such that I am able to pass the extents into r.viewshed. this is given by the variable "extcoordStr" in the below code

```
import processing
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo

rasterLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
      pointLayer=QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Tasmania_select_two')[0]

i=0
for ft in pointLayer.getFeatures():
   point = ft.geometry().asPoint()
   coordStr = '%d,%d' % (point.x(),point.y())
   coordArray = coordStr.split(',')

   #extent generation, +- 50,000Metres from point origin(coordStr)
   xMin = int(coordArray[0]) - 50000
   xMax = int(coordArray[0]) + 50000
   yMin = int(coordArray[1]) - 50000
   yMax = int(coordArray[1]) + 50000

   #Type juggling to get xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax
   extcoordStr = str(xMin) + ',' + str(xMax) + ',' + str(yMin) + ',' + str(yMax)

   outputViewshed = 'C:\Users\nightswitch57\Desktop\Script\viewshed_%i.tif' % i

   #running viewshed with observer and target heights set to 20Metres at max distance of 50Km
   outputs_0=processing.runalg("grass7:r.viewshed", rasterLayer,coordStr,20,20,50000,False, extcoordStr,0,outputViewshed)
   i = i + 1
```

**problem**
when I click run, my computer freezes up a bit task manager shows GRASS is been used but at the end there is nothing in the output folder.
in Jakobs answer he uses, I feel this might be the reason why I do not have any output in the folder I specified

```
outputViewshed = 'd:/temp/viewshed_%i.tif' % i
```

while I use

```
outputViewshed = 'C:\Users\nightswitch57\Desktop\Script\viewshed_%i.tif' % i
```

Also in addition I would much rather have the viewshed named after the point features "Site ID" which is in a column within the point shapefile (Tasmania_select_two) as currently it is supposed to name each viewshed as the number of the point feature. 
to achieve this i'm guessing I would need to append the point features Site ID to the outputViewshed variable somehow but I don't know how to.

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes (or double quoting the backward slashes) in your path separators?

Comment: you mean like this ?
    `outputViewshed = 'C:/Users/nightswitch57/Desktop/Script/viewshed_%i.tif' % i`

Comment: That is what I meant.

Comment: this produces the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/nights~1/appdata/local/temp/2/tmpwf9kd3.py", line 23
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file c:/users/nights~1/appdata/local/temp/2/tmpwf9kd3.py on line 23, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: That looks like a different problem - perhaps you want to close this question off and try posting a new question with the full command you are running, and the exact error.

Comment: the full command is the one above, it produces no erros its just that it produces no outputs as stated in my "question"

Comment: can anyone replicate this scenario please? 

all you need is a raster DEM and a shapefile containing points. activate the raster file by clicking on it and then run the above python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it's not too late for answering.

Your solution won't work because you reproduced the syntax of the `r.los` algorithm, but it is now deprecated: you probably knew that because you called the `r.viewshed` algorithm, but you forgot looking for the right way of running it.

In addition to this, you didn't see any error because you disabled the **Python Console**. In fact, I ran your code and this message appeared in the Python Console every time there was a wrong call to the algorithm (i.e. equal to the number of points):

```
Error: Wrong number of parameters
ALGORITHM: r.viewshed - Computes the viewshed of a point on an elevation raster map.
    input <ParameterRaster>
    coordinates <ParameterString>
    observer_elevation <ParameterString>
    target_elevation <ParameterString>
    max_distance <ParameterString>
    refraction_coeff <ParameterNumber>
    memory <ParameterNumber>
    -c <ParameterBoolean>
    -r <ParameterBoolean>
    -b <ParameterBoolean>
    -e <ParameterBoolean>
    GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>
    GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER <ParameterNumber>
    output <OutputRaster>
```

The above lines are self-explanatory since they take in account many parameters that you neglected (if you want to know what these new parameters mean, please refer to the documentation of the [r.viewshed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.viewshed.html) algorithm).

I edited your code and it works by now (remember to adapt the parameters to your specific case):

```
import processing
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo

rasterLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
pointLayer=QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Tasmania_select_two')[0]

i=0
for ft in pointLayer.getFeatures():
    point = ft.geometry().asPoint()
    coordStr = '%d,%d' % (point.x(),point.y())
    coordArray = coordStr.split(',')

    #extent generation, +- 50,000Metres from point origin(coordStr)
    xMin = int(coordArray[0]) - 50000
    xMax = int(coordArray[0]) + 50000
    yMin = int(coordArray[1]) - 50000
    yMax = int(coordArray[1]) + 50000

    #Type juggling to get xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax
    extcoordStr = str(xMin) + ',' + str(xMax) + ',' + str(yMin) + ',' + str(yMax)

    outputViewshed = 'C:/Users/nightswitch57/Desktop/Script/viewshed_%i.tif' % i

    #running viewshed with observer and target heights set to 20Metres at max distance of 50Km
    outputs_0=processing.runalg('grass7:r.viewshed', rasterLayer, coordStr, '0', '0', '800', 0.14286, 500, False, False, False, False, extcoordStr, 0, outputViewshed)
    i = i + 1
```

Two final notes:

1. You need to use slashes when setting the output path, otherwise the above code won't work;
2. I posted a working solution for the code which you proposed. If you want to rename your output using a value from a field instead of a number, you may use this line: `outputViewshed = 'C:/Users/nightswitch57/Desktop/Script/viewshed_%s.tif' % (ft["ID_IN"])` (the changes are in the using of `%s` and the name of the field).

Comment: hey mate thank you for this, i'll give it a go in a weeks time when I renter the project.

Comment: @AshanLazarus any news? Does it work?

Comment: thanks for following up mate sorry this project has hit the back burner. i'll ry set up some time for it this week, I really do need to give it a shot. I sincerely thank you for helping me out with this. i'll keep you posted of the results when I get back into it.