# QGIS Modeler if/else condition, custom script for Modeler

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-modeler, if-else

I want to make a simple if/else function inside my Model and I wanted to know if it's possible or not.

[image]

I want this thing to do that if an Input for 'Segment Layer' is selected that it 
doesn't have to execute the 'Segmentation(meanshift)' and uses 'Segment Layer' instead as an Input for the next Process.

the Inputs for the 'Segmentation(meanshift)'are as follows

[image]

Update after trying to implement Joseph's answer:
I used the following code and got this error
[image]

Update 2, after replacing the parameters I get an error in line 28 this is were 'else:' stands

```
##Example=name
##BGREN=optional raster
##Segment_Layer=optional vector
##output=output vector

if BGREN is not None:
    processing.runalg('otb:segmentationmeanshift', \
    -BGREN\
    -0\
    -70\
    -70\
    -0.1\
    -100\
    -100\
    -0\
    -0\
    -0\
    -'True'\
    -'False'\
    -1\
    -0.1\
    -'Layer'\
    -'DN'\
    -1024\
    -1\
    -0\
    -output)
else:
    output=Segment_Layer
```

[image]

Update it works :)
after a few try's and with Joseph help this code now works like a charm, the final trick was to replace two optional values with 'None'.

```
##Example=name
##BGREN=optional raster
##Segment_Layer=optional vector
##output=output vector

if BGREN is not None:
    processing.runalg('otb:segmentationmeanshift', \
    BGREN, \
    0, \
    70, \
    70, \
    0.1, \
    100, \
    100, \
    0, \
    0, \
    None, \
    True, \
    False, \
    1, \
    0.1, \
    'Layer', \
    'DN', \
    1024, \
    1, \
    None, \
    output)
else:
    output=Segment_Layer
```

Comment: I think you will need to use a **custom script** inside your modeler in order to use _if/else_ statements correctly.

Comment: @Joseph that's what I thought too, the Problem is I'm not as good in scripting as i would like to be, I pretty much have no expirience at all...

Comment: @Andreas I confirm what Joseph wrote in its comment. However, I think you may get more help from the community if you edit your question and give the possibility to get some hints with Python (adding also a proper tag)...

Comment: @Andreas - Replace all parameter names with the values instead. E.g. '-filter, 0\' should just be '0, \' etc. Also, it's more helpful to post the actual code than a screenshot. This allows people to copy/paste your code for testing instead of having to type it all out :)

Comment: @Joseph all done but as you can see there is something new, and thanks for the info I'll keep that the copy/paste thing in my mind :)

Comment: @Andreas - Edited my post. Also, you should accept answers **after** they have solved your problem ;)

Comment: @Joseph I edited my post with the now working code, your help was much needed and I'm really glad you took some of your precious time to help me with this :)
as of right now it's executing the algorithm and i have to wait for the results but it looks really promising, thank you again :)

Comment: @Andreas - Awesome! Glad you got it running and hopefully the results will be correct. And it was my pleasure :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, a **custom script** may be the way to go in this situation. You can create one from:

```
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script
```

The following script sets the input parameters as *optional* along with an *if/else* statement depending on which parameter contains a layer. So if a layer was selected for `BGREN`, it will perform the [segmentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/otb/segmentation.html#segmentation-meanshift) tool and sets the output; otherwise the output will be the layer selected from `Segment_Layer`.

Here is a possible script:

```
##Example=name
##BGREN=optional raster
##Segment_Layer=optional vector
##output=output vector

if BGREN is not None:
    processing.runalg('otb:segmentationmeanshift', \
    -BGREN, \
    -filter, \
    -filter.meanshift.spatialr, \
    -filter.meanshift.ranger, \
    -filter.meanshift.thres, \
    -filter.meanshift.maxiter, \
    -filter.meanshift.minsize, \
    -mode, \
    -mode.vector.outmode, \
    -mode.vector.inmask, \
    -mode.vector.neighbor, \
    -mode.vector.stitch, \
    -mode.vector.minsize, \
    -mode.vector.simplify, \
    -mode.vector.layername, \
    -mode.vector.fieldname, \
    -mode.vector.tilesize, \
    -mode.vector.startlabel, \
    -mode.vector.ogroptions, \
    -output)
else:
    output=Segment_Layer
```

The parameters for the `otb:segmentationmeanshift` look scary! Unfortunately, I do not have Orfeo installed so cannot test this tool. However, the parameters are [shown here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/otb/segmentation.html#id34), you just need to type them in instead of using the GUI. Once done, add the script into your modeler using `BGREN` and `Segment_Layer` as input layers:

[image: Script parameters]

Also, in your modeler, you may need to change the *Required* parameter definition of `BGREN` and `Segment_Layer`:

[image: Parameter definition]

Then connect the output of the script to your NDVI tool.

---

I tested this to some extent using other tools which worked depending on which input layer was selected so hopefully it will work for your modeler!

---

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the code you used slightly modified (you need the commas to separate the parameters, `True` and `False` statements don't require quotes around them, the backward slash is just for readability but will include it as a one-liner):

```
##Example=name
##BGREN=optional raster
##Segment_Layer=optional vector
##output=output vector

if BGREN is not None:
    processing.runalg('otb:segmentationmeanshift', \
    BGREN, \
    0, \
    70, \
    70, \
    0.1, \
    100, \
    100, \
    0, \
    0, \
    0, \
    True, \
    False, \
    1, \
    0.1, \
    'Layer', \
    'DN', \
    1024, \
    1, \
    0, \
    output)
else:
    output=Segment_Layer
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
##Example=name
##BGREN=optional raster
##Segment_Layer=optional vector
##output=output vector

if BGREN is not None:
    processing.runalg('otb:segmentationmeanshift',BGREN,0,70,70,0.1,100,100,0,0,0,True,False,1,0.1,'Layer','DN',1024,1,0,output)
else:
    output=Segment_Layer
```

Comment: I was adding a comment for encouraging @Andreas to edit its question and give the possibility to get some hints with Python for receiving more help, but you were faster!

Comment: @mgri - I would encourage you to post that comment as the OP might want to edit some details in and hopefully encourage others to post a possible solution :)

Comment: @Joseph damn that's a lot more than i thought it would be :O anyway I'll try to recreate this and leave a feedback if i got it to work, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Most welcome! I probably did overthink this so it may be a good idea to edit your question as @mgri suggested so that a more suitable python solution or such can be posted =)

Comment: @Joseph I updated the question so hopefully we get more answers and maybe even one I can recreate, as for your solution i may sound really stupid now but anyway where should I write my parameters probably after the comma, thing is i always get an error...

Comment: @Andreas Joseph wrote the required parameters from the algorithm: you need to directly replace them with yours (see at the end of the code in this [asnwer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226178/87487) for an example).

Comment: @mgri i still get an error it tells me the following:

Uncaught error while executing algorithm
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
       self.processAlgorithm(progress)
     File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 321, in processAlgorithm
       exec((script), ns)
     File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
   TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'unicode'

Comment: @Andreas - Could you [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/228224/edit) your question to include the code you used in your script? If a parameter requires letters, you need to put it inside quotes so that it is recognised as a string. You don't have to do this for numbers.

Comment: @Joseph I updated the question, i hope you see the error I made as I said in the beginning I'm really stupid when it comes to things like this :)

Comment: @Andreas - Not stupid at all, _everyone_ has to learn from the beginning =)