# Determining elevation of given coordinate (point) of rasterized .tiff-file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, python-2.7

Currently, I'm developing a plug-in with Python for QGIS, which allows me to perform Line-Of-Sight Calculations. For the calculations, I'm using a python-script which calls modules like "r.viewshed" from GRASS to create the viewshed-maps.

R.viewshed requires some raster-file as input, and that's why I'm using  a method called "r.in.gdal" in my python-script to rasterize the elevation-map (tiff.file). The Line-Of-Sight Calculations are working properly, but there's just one problem:

r.viewshed requires one parameter called "observer_elevation". As for now, I've "hardcoded" this parameter since I don't know the **elevation (height)** **of** the **given coordinate**.

**Does someone know, how to retrieve the elevation from a given coordinate so that I can process it in my python-script?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably confusing on how using the parameters for the [r.viewshed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.viewshed.html) GRASS module. In fact, from the manual of `r.viewshed` algorithm:

> **observer_elevation**=value
>
> Viewing elevation above the ground
>
> Default: 1.75

This parameter doesn't refer to the elevation (height) of the given coordinate, but to the height of the observer. This observer usually is a man (this justifies the default value of 1.75 m), but you may adjust it on the basis of your needs.

For an example on how to run `r.viewshed` using Python, see also:

[Programmatically performing viewshed on points from a shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207091/programmatically-performing-viewshed-on-points-from-a-shapefile/226178#226178)

Comment: Thanks so much! So this means that the observer_elevation is per default set to | ELEVATION ON THE THE GIVEN POINT + 1,75 | . Is that correct?

Comment: @AleksMaksimovic yes, it should be like that.